# jQuery to select all anchor elements in unordered list

Tags: jquery, html

I have an unordered list with the following structure.

If I click the link in List Item 1, I want to be able to select all of the links (anchor tags) underneath List Item 1 and change the class to be "yes".

How?

```
    <ul>
        <li><div><span><a class="no" href="#">List Item 1</a></span></div>
            <ul>
                <li><div><span><a class="no" href="#">Sub List Item 1</a></span></div></li>
                <li><div><span><a class="no" href="#">Sub List Item 2</a></span></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><div><span><a class="no" href="#">Sub Sub List Item 1</a></span></div></li>
                        <li><div><span><a class="no" href="#">Sub Sub List Item 2</a></span></div></li>
                        <li><div><span><a class="no" href="#">Sub Sub List Item 3</a></span></div></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><div><span><a class="no" href="#">Sub List Item 3</a></span></div></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div><span><a class="no" href="#">List Item 2</a></span></div>
            <ul>
                <li><div><span><a class="no" href="#">Sub List Item 5</a></span></div></li>
                <li><div><span><a class="no" href="#">Sub List Item 6</a></span></div></li>
                <li><div><span><a class="no" href="#">Sub List Item 7</a></span></div></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**Answer**

```
        $(href).closest('li').find('a').each(function (index, child) {
            $(child).removeClass('no').addClass('yes');
            //Do more logic here
        });
```

Comment: Do you really need an anchor inside a span inside a div inside a list ?

Comment: @Blender - I have tried several different things.

Comment: @Robert: It'd be best if you posted your current attempt.

Comment: @adeneo - I did not choose the structure. I am using the wijmo tree and this is a small sample of the generated html.

Comment: @Blender My latest attempt is to try using $("li[data-item-id='12345'] a"); Each list item does have an attr called data-item-id on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.no').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').find('a').andSelf().addClass('yes').removeClass('no');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph. Your code did exactly what I asked for. I needed a slightly different approach to this solution.